# BigQuery Google Analytics Export Processing Time Management

Tags: google-bigquery

Our company has many schedule reports in BigQuery that generate aggregation tables of Google Analytics data.  Because we cannot control when Google Analytics data is imported into our BigQuery environment we keep getting days with no data.

This means we then have to manually run the data for missing days.

I have edited my schedule query to keep pushing back the time of day the scheduled query runs however it is now running around 8 AM.  These queries are for reports for stakeholders and stakeholders are requesting them earlier.  Is there any way to ensure Google Analytics export to BigQuery processing times?

You may also think about a Scheduled Query solution that reruns at a later time if the requested table isn't available yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't current add a conditional trigger to a BigQuery scheduled query.

You could manually add a fail safe to your query to check for table from yesterday using a combination of the code below and `DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`:

```
 SELECT
 MAX(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%F %T', TIMESTAMP(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',
 REGEXP_EXTRACT(_TABLE_SUFFIX,r'^\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d')))  ))
 FROM `DATASET.ga_sessions_*`  AS ga_sessions
```

Obviously this will fail if the conditions are not met and will not retry, which I understand is not an advancement on your current setup.

I've encountered this many times in the past and eventually had to move my data pipelines to another solution, as scheduled queries are still quite simplistic.

I would recommend you take a look at CRMint for simple pipelines into BigQuery:
https://github.com/google/crmint

If you still find this too simplistic then you should look at [Google Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer/), where you can check a table exists before running a particular job in a pipeline: